# update column with comma separated value

Tags: sql

In my SQL table, I have a column named "user_id" with comma separated value like this: a,b,c,d and I just wonder how can I update this column without removing old values. I want to update this column to a,b,c,d,e and in other step to a,b,c,d,e,f.

I wrote this query, but it removes old values and does not not update values with comma separated list:

```
UPDATE multiusers SET user_id = '" . $userID . "' WHERE hwid = '" . $hwid."'
```

Comment: Fix your database, so you have a junction table instead of a comma-separated list.

Comment: Best approach: Normalize your database so you don't store *multiple values* in *one field*.  Failing that: Combine your strings in application code, then update the database with the new string value.  As far as SQL is concerned, all you're storing is a string.  It doesn't know what "comma separated values" are.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update a column and append a value just do :-

```
UPDATE multiusers 
SET user_id = user_id + "new user" 
WHERE hwid = $hwid
```

This just appends a value to the existing value in SQL SERVER db at least, other databases may have different concatenation methods. I think your questions points to a fundamental design issue in your database and I would suggest rethinking this.

Comment: I did with this: `$newUser = ",".$userID;`  and   `UPDATE multiusers SET user_id = user_id + '" . $newUser . "' WHERE hwid = '" . $hwid."'`  But have this error:  `Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: ',5'`

Answer (score 0):

You are treating a field as a table. Even when you can do, it's a very bad approach. You should have as many records on multiusers table as userid's you have. But if you insist in your approach then you will have to create a quite complex query to retrieve the value of userid field, move to an array and compare it with the new value to make sure you doesn't insert duplicates in the field. Something like a cursor may work for you.